# Multiple Part Wordpress Post

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I want to create a blog with stories. Where each story may have multiple chapters. I want to publish chapter wise. Is there any plugin to handle this in WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

You could use core functionalities like categories or even tags as the root of your stories and publish each chapter as new post in this category or with the assigned tag.

Then you could display your stories on an archive page with a custom loop, depending on how/what you want to display (eg. title, content, excerpt...).

Comment: How to add next and prev within the stories to other chapters? Also how to sort the chapters in reverse order?

Comment: It's quite easy to do with custom loops in your theme's files and probably you will find pre made themes which already have those functionalities. But for now I can't help you more without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the Custom Post Type. Here is the plugin you may use.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/

You can set your Stories as Custom post type and Chapter as a Custom taxonomy. You can also call them on any page, sort them as your chapter vise, you can also show limited chapters stories, etc. with the `WP_Query`.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/